# Customizing schemas in marshmallow

Tags: python, validation, marshmallow

Consider the following schema:

```
from pprint import pprint

from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate, ValidationError


class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str(required= True, validate=validate.Length(min=1))
    permission = fields.Str(required =True, validate=validate.OneOf(["read", "write", "admin"]))
    age = fields.Int(required=True, validate=validate.Range(min=18, max=40))
```

Now suppose in some case, I want the `age` field to not have to be required.

In the below code, how would I specify this? Can I do something like:

```
user_schema = UserSchema(many=True, age =fields.Int(required=False, validate=validate.Range(min=18, max=40))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could modify the `required` attribute for the field but I wouldn't recommend that.

I would remove the `required` constraint on the field and add a [schema-level validator](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending.html?highlight=validates_schema#schema-level-validation) that would fail if the field is missing only when business logic makes it required.